# Is there a way to search for "Answer your own question" questions?

Tags: support, search

I have some ideas for some "Answer your own question" questions on one of the beta sites but I was hoping to find some others to check the style being used for them, but I can't think of a way to locate the questions other than working out a query on [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Is there a shortcut search I can use to find a list of Q&A questions on a StackExchange site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the questions that are self-answered from SEDE with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/204498/questions-that-are-self-answered)

```
select top 1000 q.id as [Post Link]
     , q.owneruserid as [User Linkl]
     , q.creationdate as [Asked on]
     , a.creationdate as [Answered On] 
from posts q 
inner join posts a on a.id = q.AcceptedAnswerId
where q.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
and a.posttypeid = 2 -- A
and a.owneruserid = q.owneruserid
```

You basically join the posts table with itself on the `id` and `acceptedanswerid` and where the `owneruserid` of both are equal are self-answered questions.

Do notice that SEDE is only updated weekly.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way. But would be good if was.